# With Ruby on Rails, how do I upload from local host to the remote server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, upload

I'm really new to web development and using Ubuntu 12.04 to develop.

Do I need to upload all the files like config, log created by Rails when creating this project?

Your answers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the files required as needed to run the app in localhost. Current log files are probably from using the app in the localhost environment so they can be excluded.

Take note that if you are uploading to a site such as Heroku, which uses postgresql, your Gemfile will need indicators if you use another database system. For example:

```
#Gemfile

# if using sqlite3 in your local environment during development
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# if using Heroku, postgresql is used, and the 'production' group 
# will be automagically used
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm uploading to "200MB Host". So would just uploading all the files be enough?

Comment: Hi, http://200mbhost.com/web_hosting.html says that free hosting does not support Ruby. Furthermore, the host may not have direct access to all the Ruby Gems.

Consider Heroku for deployment. It is a good environment with a free option (pay if you need extra computing power if needed, as needed), supporting Ruby on Rails very well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need all files generated by rails like config files almost, but the logs is not required.

Comment: I've uploaded all the files under the folder "mydomain.com" but when I tried to access it shows that "Error 403 - Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this page or directory listing on the server."

Comment: generally this message means there are privilege issues in your server's configuration. which server you use?

Comment: The free web host "200MB Host"

Comment: As stonefruit mentioned above "200mbhost.com/web_hosting.html says that free hosting does not support Ruby", I will try using Heroku.